# What's the difference between transparent proxy and explicit proxy

Tags: iptables, transparent-proxy

I've set up a transparent proxy with `squid` listening on 8080(http) 8443(https), and it works.

In addition, I set the iptables to redirect the request.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

If I set up an explicit proxy to replace squid, http still works, but https doesn't work (https proxy performs a MITM, and I trust the certificate).

I want to know the difference between using iptables REDIRECT and setting browser's proxy explicitly. Does the proxy process it somehow differently?

Answer (score 5):

## How proxies work

### How a transparent proxy works

The browser thinks it is talking to the web server, and the proxy intercepts this traffic, and performs whatever tasks it needs to.

### How an explicit proxy works

The browser knows it is talking to a proxy, and asks the proxy to load up the site that it wants to load instead.

## Benefits of each type

### Transparent

- No need to configure on each client
- Can be used by software that has no proxy settings

### Explicit

- More obvious that traffic is being monitored
- Can work in places that a transparent proxy would break stuff
- More likely to give useful error messages if the proxy fails

Answer (score 2):

The browser talks differently. With explicit proxy, it will issue a special `CONNECT` verb whenever it needs anything over https. With transparent proxy, it will issue normal `GET` or `POST`, but never `CONNECT`.

This particular difference doesn't happen with insecure http.